# R Help For Martingale Simulation

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to make a martingale simulation in R where I bet an amount and if I win I bet the same amount but if I lose, I bet double the amount. I do this until I run out of money to bet or have bet 100 times. I then have to do the martingale simulation 100 times. When I apply my code, I get the following errors;

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}" (I think all brackets are accounted for)
>
> Error in martingale_function(m, c, n, p) : 
>            could not find function "martingale_function"

(I don't know why I get this error)

```
m = amount to bet
c = initial bet
n= number of round
p = probability of winning 


martingale_function <- function(m,c,n,p){
  for(i in 1:n){
    betting_money <- m
    amount_bet <- c
    end_Sim <- FALSE
    while(!end_Sim){
      if(runif(1) = p){
        betting_money <- betting_money + amount_bet
        amount_bet <- amount_bet
      }    
      else {
        betting_money <- betting_money - amount_bet
        amount_bet <- amount_bet*2
      }
      if(betting_money <= 0|i=100){# if we have no more money left to bet or have done it 100 times we stop
        end_Sim <- TRUE
  }
}   return(betting_money)  
    }
}
iteration_function <- function(m,c,n,p){
  for(i in 1:100){
    return(data.frame(Iteriation=i,AmountLeft = martingale_function(m,c,n,p)))
  }
}

iteration_function(650,5,100,18/38)
```

Answer (score 2):

Errors:

- Line 13: shouldn't be `runif(1) = p`, perhaps you meant `runif(1) < p`?
- Line 15: I suspect you meant `amount_bet <- c` instead of `amount_bet <- amount_bet`
- Line 21: should be `i==100` not `i=100`
- Line 26: `}` should be moved before `return()` line

Things that don't affect execution of code, but should be changed:

- Line 16: it's good programming practice to write `} else {` one one line
- Line 24: you should move `return()` to its own line

Also, I'm not sure why there are two `for` loops. It seems like you only need one.

---

Here's my re-write of your code (with some assumptions about exactly what you're trying to do):

```
# write betting function
martingale <- function(m, c, p) {
    money   <- m
    betsize <- c
    i <- 1
    while(money > 0 & i <= 100) {
        if(runif(1) < p) {
            money <- money + betsize
            betsize <- c
        } else {
            money <- money - betsize
            betsize <- betsize * 2
        }
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(money)
}

# run it 100 times
n <- 100
res_df <- data.frame(iteration = rep(NA_integer_, n), amountleft = rep(NA_real_, n))
for (i in 1:n) {
    res_df[i , "iteration"]  <- i
    res_df[i , "amountleft"] <- martingale(m=650, c=5, p=18/38)
}
```

Comment: `if(runif(1) = p){` also should have 2 `=` i.e. `if(runif(1) == p){`

Comment: My code had an error.  I originally wrote `bet_size` in one place that should have been `betsize`.  My code above is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the line where you write:

```
if(runif(1) = p){}
```

Shouldn't that be a double equals sign?

Comment: Probably better as a comment but definitely useful